# How can I make my discord bot edit its own last message after data is ready

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

My discord bot has a command to lookup data from an API and sometimes it takes time so I want my bot to tell the user that.

The initial message is: `message.channel.send({embed: { color: 0x80ff00, description: "Looking for data"}})`

How can I make the bot edit the message with the data after the data embed is ready?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
message.channel
  .send({embed: { color: 0x80ff00, description: "Looking for data"}})
  .then(embed => {
    // here `embed` is the message that was sent to the channel
    someAsyncOperation().then(data => {
      embed.edit({embed: {description: "Found the data: " + data}});
    });
  });
```

See [TextChannel#send](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send) and [Message#edit](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=edit).

Answer (score 1):

Using .then:

```
message.channel.send({embed: { color: 0x80ff00, description: "Looking for data"}})
    .then(msg => {
        msg.edit('Something');
    });
```

Using async await:

```
const msg = await message.channel.send({embed: { color: 0x80ff00, description: "Looking for data"}});
msg.edit('data');
```